# How to edit grid in Visual Fox Pro?

Tags: forms, grid, append, edit, visual-foxpro

I am having trouble editing a grid in my form, which displays the data found in one of my tables. I can't modify already existing fields or add new ones.

```
Readonly=false
allowaddnew=true
enabled=true
```

Comment: How are you trying to edit the grid? If you're trying to do it while the program is running, it doesn't work like that.

Comment: Oh, I was trying to edit it while my form was running. is there no way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "edit" here? Are you trying to change the grid layout or just modify the data that's displayed? You can do both, but they're quite different. I think you mean edit the data. Are you able to edit the table in other places (say, in a Browse window)? If not, then perhaps the table is readonly.

Comment: Yes, i want to edit the data in the grid. I can change the data by opening the database table, or by the browse window, but i can't edit anything in the grid. ReadOnly is set to false. I tried a completely new project, form and empty grid, but it still doesn't let me write in the grid. I would like to know what settings should a grid have in order for it to be editable.

Comment: *edit: using the browse command in the form doesn't let me update the data in the table either. could there be something wrong with the database?

Comment: How is the data getting to the grid? Are you setting the grid's `RecordSource` property to your table?

Comment: Yes, in the recordsource i have a select command which connects it with the grid, and the recordsourcetype is set to 4-sql statement.

Comment: That's the issue. The SQL Statement you're running is putting its results into a cursor. By default, query results in a cursor are readonly. Is there a reason you're using the SQL statement recordsource instead of Alias?

Comment: omg i can't believe it was this simple. i set it to sql statement, because i was using a select command in the record source, but now i tried it with Alias, and it works just great. Thank you to everyone who helped. And thank you @TamarE.Granor for pointing out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not in the grid. It sounds like you need to do some homework on your options to connect to your data. VFP is designed to allow you to connect your controls directly to a VFP table, or to a view that comes from either a VFP table or a SQL database server.

If you bind your grid directly to a VFP table, then each field you change is immediately reflected back in the table. This sounds like what you want, but consider what happens if you want to add a new record. You will need to have some code to add a new blank record to the table, and populate some key fields, which sounds easy enough. But then what happens when the user start doing data entry and then decides they want to abandon it, or they lose their connection - now you have data in your table that you need to add more code and maintenance procedures to clean up.

Some people solved this problem by creating temporary tables (using the form's Data Environment Init method) and then binding the grid to that. Then if the user clicks Save, the developer had to write code to synchronize the data back to the production tables. But then MS introduced updatable views, which allow you to query either a VFP table or a SQL Server and bind your grid to that instead. The benefit was that you could then use a 'buffering' method to automate the synchronization of data back into your production table without writing laborious code to map all the fields and business logic around create/update/delete. This guy wrote a good article on buffering modes.  https://www.levelextreme.com/ShowHeaderArticleOneItem.aspx?ID=39374

Many developers have been down this path and the issues around using buffering are complex and take a significant amount of time to understand. People created an entire businesses around selling developer tools that managed the complexity with this issue, but in my experience, there were always issues that were not obvious and it took a lot of experimentation to figure it out.